# NodeJS unable to import Sequelize.js model (ES6)

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I'm running NodeJS with Express and Seqeulize and I have a file  `controllers/rooms.js` importing Room from `models/room.js`.

```
import Room from '../models'

export function list(req, res) {
    return Room
        .findAll()
        .then((rooms) => res.status(200).send(rooms))
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error))
}
```

Bellow is `models/room.js` (There is also `index.js` file generate by sequelize-cli in the same directory)

```
'use strict'

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    const Room = sequelize.define('Room', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    })

    return Room
}
```

And I have a route `app.get('/rooms', list)`, but when I access this route I get this error:

```
TypeError: _models2.default.findAll is not a function
    at list (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/app/database/controllers/rooms.js:21:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at query (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at Function.handle (/Users/matis/Documents/apps/node-docker-test/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:174:10)
```

I'm sure I have my imports/exports messed up but I don't know how.

`models/index.js` file bellow

```
'use strict'

import { readdirSync } from 'fs'
import { basename as _basename, join } from 'path'
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
const basename = _basename(__filename)
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env]
const db = {}

let sequelize
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config)
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config)
}

readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
    })
    .forEach(file => {
        const model = sequelize['import'](join(__dirname, file))
        db[model.name] = model
    })

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db)
    }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

export default db
```

**It works when I call it like this:**
`return Room.Room.findAll()...`
Therefore i can rename the import to this:
`import models from '../models'`
and call it this way:
`return models.Room.findAll()...`

However why can't I just call it `return Room.findAll()...`, how should the import be formulated ??

Comment: can you please share your database connection file . you might have problem with that file. because you are trying with the .defualt key
you can try directly model.findAll() method

Comment: I don't think there is a problem there, but do you want the `config.json` or `index.js` in models folder ?

Comment: try module.exports = db.

Comment: on the controller try with `import {Room} from '../models'` or `import {room} from '../models'`

Comment: @VassilisPallas that didn't work, I tried that earlier, but I edited my question with working code, but I'm not satisfied with it

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have babel setup for using ES6 imports you can try this approach to export a Sequelize model in ES6.

// db config file

```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database.name,
  config.database.user,
  config.database.password,
  {
    host: config.database.host,
    dialect: config.database.dialect,
    pool: config.database.pool,
    operatorsAliases: false
  }
);
```

// Model

```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../database/db';

const User = sequelize.define(
  'table_name',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  { freezeTableName: true }
);

export default User;
```

Answer (score 1):

Last time when I worked with Sequelize it was not working well with ES6 features. My guess is that `models/room.js` is not exporting model properly due to `export default`. You can try changing that line to old style `module.exports`;

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
.....
To
.....
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
```

and see if that solves the import problem.

When importing in controller you can do this;

```
const Room = require('../models').Room;
```

this is old way to do imports and now your code should work. :)

If you want to try with ES6 you can do something like;

```
import {Room} from '../models'
```

I'm not sure if this ES6 import works here!

Comment: Same Error :/ Do you have a better suggestion for different ORM ?

Comment: can you upload index.js file?

Comment: Have you tried without 'use-restrict'? remove that and try. And remember to restart server.

Comment: Tried without `'user-strict'` didn't help, attached `index.js` file

Comment: From error I can only see that when you import your model it somehow imports `default` keyword and then tries to call .findAll on that which doesn't exist. I think it should work with updated export in model.

Comment: small typo in comments, 'use-strict'.

Comment: @tahirwaseer Your updated answer doesn't work, I'm getting this error now: `Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined`. However I updated my question with working code, but I'm not satisfied with it.

Comment: Have you changed your import to `const Room = require('../models').Room;`

Comment: @tahirwaseer Yes I did

Comment: Then I can't see why it is not working. In working state when you can use models.Room.findAll without issue then it only comes to one thing; index.js in models/ returns and object with all models and we need to extract Room model which can be done in two ways I've listed in answer, 1) using `require` old way 2) using destructuring (ES6)  way. Then you sould be able to call `return Room.findAll`.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to setup the existing code and faced the above issue. The issue got resolved by downgrading my node version to 10.18.0 from the latest version.

It seems to be that the code was originally developed using node version 10.